# Flutter: AOT snapshotter exited with code -1073741571

Tags: flutter, dart

My Flutter project does not build in release mode on Android anymore. iOS is fine and debug mode on Android builds (after I changed ext.kotlin_version from 1.7.10 to 1.8.20)

STACKTRACE:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 7 in release mode...
Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code -1073741571
Target android_aot_release_android-arm64 failed: Exception: AOT snapshotter exited with code -1073741571


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1157

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

#12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
Could not find an option named "stacktrace".


Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.
```

FLUTTER DOCTOR:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.12, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1702], locale en-DE)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.78.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I tired flutter clean, copy and pasting content of the jre into the jbr Folder (or other way, i forgot), removing src/flutter and reinstall, downgrading flutter. Expected any to fix it, but they didn't.

Comment: Okay, I "solved" it.
Removing the markup_text dependency solved the problem.